# How do I programmatically create a webform from a newly created node?

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

This is the code I am using.

```
function walk_handler_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if (method_exists($entity, 'getType') && $entity->getType() === 'walk') {
    $elements = [];

    $elements[] = [
      '#title' => 'This is a test',
      '#type' => 'textfield'
    ];

    $webform = Webform::create([
      'id' => 'walk_' . $entity->id(),
      'title' => 'Test',
      'elements' => Yaml::encode($elements),
      'settings' => Webform::getDefaultSettings()
    ]);

    $webform->save();
  }
}
```

Somehow, this hook will get triggered twice: once when the node is getting submitted, and another time when the webform is getting created. The result is that I'm getting an error about the `Webform` object not having a `getType()` method and this is why I'm using `method_exists()` in the condition.

I can't seem to find any hook that would only focus on nodes and not on webforms.

What other hook can I use to react to new nodes being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.8.x) is called for every entity being saved which means that, since that `hook_entity_presave()` implementation is saving an entity, it is being invoked twice.

Using `method_exists()` is generally wrong, as in PHP is generally preferable to check if the object is an instance of a class implementing an interface or a class extending another class.
In this case, it's also wrong because the code isn't supposed to run for every entity that has a `getType()` method, but just for nodes. (While nodes are the only Drupal core entities with that method, there could be entities implemented from third-party modules that define that method, possibly for different purposes.)

You should check the entity type as [said from berramou](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288363/199) or use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.8.x) as [said from No Sssweat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288364/199).
Since the question is asking how to create a webform when a node is created, I would rather use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.8.x) which is invoked:

- Only when an entity is created, not when an entity is updated
- After the entity has been saved in the storage

Using this hook has the benefit of not creating a new webform every time a node is edited. The implementation code is also simpler, as it doesn't require checking the webform is already created for that node.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) to only focus on nodes and not on webforms, you can check the entity type like in the following code.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function YourModule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node') {
    // Do you webform creation code here 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`hook_entity_presave()` runs when any entity is inserted or saved; thus, it runs twice in your case, since you have a Node and a Webform entity being saved.

You would have to add a conditional to check the entity type as [@berramou's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/288363/27710) suggests.

Alternatively, you could use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x) and target the node.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()
 */
function MODULE_NAME_node_presave(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  // your code goes here
}
```